# Find the position of a control in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I need to find the x and y coordinates of a control, but I'm not sure where to begin. The only solutions that I've found on the internet use MFC, and I want to avoid using that. So, is there a way to find the coordinates of a control without using MFC?

Using FindWindow to find the control:

```
    RECT cr;
    HWND chWnd   =   FindWindow("SunAwtCanvas", NULL);
    GetWindowRect(chWnd, &cr);
    cw   =   cr.right;
    ch   =   cr.bottom;
    cx   =   cr.left;
    cy   =   cr.top;
    cout << chWnd << endl;
```

chWnd is 0 when it should have the hWnd of the control.

Comment: It's a control in which a game is embedded. Its not a standard control that you'd find in a GUI. I'm not sure how else to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

use GetWindowRect on the hwnd of the control (every control has its own hwnd): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx. this will give you the left, right, top and bottom allowing to know the bounds of the control, and also work out its height and width

Comment: Ok, I know how to use GetWindowRect, so that's good. Now I just need to find the hWnd of the control. After searching for an answer, it looks like you need to know the ID of the control to find its hWnd, and I have no idea how to find the ID.

Comment: use findwindow, you can find by class name or window name. use spy++ to find out what one or both of those are. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: OK, so I used FindWindow with the class name, but it returns 0. @bizzehdee

Comment: It should be pointed out that not *every* control has its own HWND. There are also windowless controls (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/11/371042.aspx), which are commonly used inside browsers, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for getting HWND is bad.

Cite from MSDN: [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Retrieves a handle to the top-level window whose class name and window
>   name match the specified strings. This function does not search child
>   windows. This function does not perform a case-sensitive search.

Use [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix it, then?

Comment: Saw your edit and changed the offending line to FindWindowEx(hWnd, NULL, "SunAwtCanvas", NULL);. hWnd is the hWnd of the target window. It still returns 0, so am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What say GetLastError() ? :)

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work. I'm not sure what I changed, but it works now. The only problem is that the control is the size of the whole client, even though the actual game is at 800x600. Spy++ says that there are 4 SunAwtCanvases, so maybe one of those is 800x600. Is there any way to find the position of a specific one?

Comment: From FindWindowEx docs: The search begins with the next child window in the Z order.

Comment: What I'm getting from that is that I need to hwnd of the 3rd child window? How do I do that?